# Android app can't grammar good: "You perform this action for another 1seconds"

Tags: bug, android-app

I accidentally touched "upvote" twice, and I saw this message:

[image]
I'm *assuming* it meant "You cannot perform this action for another 1 second," but there's so many errors I can't be sure ;-)

Comment: Clearly the app thinks that's a great question and is issuing you a command.

Comment: I couldn't agree more: That question in your screenshot is awesome.

Comment: I accidentally an action.